# Why random forest performs better when converting categorical attributes to numerical ones?

Tags: categorical-data, random-forest, weka

I have a dataset with 15 attributes, 6 are numerical and 9 are categorical. Among the categorical ones, some have about 3 levels, some about 10 levels and 2 of them about 500 levels. I'm training a model for binary classification.

When I convert the categorical attributes to numerical ones (using the so-called dummy coding technique), my performance results get better, to a fairly considerable extent.

Is this something expected to happen based on my dataset information or if not, what are some potential reasons that could cause that?

Comment: Are you using a specific library? If so, please add this information. Further, are you sure that increase in accuracy can only be attributed to feature encoding or is there any randomness in your model (feature selection) that could otherwise be the reason for improvement? Can you replicate this issue?

Comment: I'm using Weka library inside RapidMiner (added Weka tag to question) and I don't do any feature selection after encoding attributes.